# How much information is in a hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-information, atomic-physics, hydrogen, information

How much information is contained in a hydrogen atom (a bound electron and proton) at room temperature?

There are [bounds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63425/what-is-the-real-world-significance-of-the-bekenstein-bound) that set limits on the amount of mass/energy that can exist in a given region of space, which is apparently about 1MB for the mass and approximate "radius" of a hydrogen atom.

On the other hand, surely the system contains some information. I can make a measurement of the mass, 1.007825 Da, yielding a handful of bits. I can ask "how many quarks does it contain" and the answer is three, uud, yielding some more bits. I can ask what the possible energy levels of the electron are, and write down the orbitals in a page or so. I can ask what the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are, and get a couple more pages. I can ask more sophisticated questions like how the quarks inside the proton behave.

One could also make use of a speculative mass-energy-information equivalence due to [Vopson](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/adv/article/9/9/095206/1076232) giving $3.19×10^{-38} Kg/bit$ at $300K$, we obtain $5.2471 \times 10^{10} bit$, or about 6.56GB.

To get at all of it, perhaps one has to tear it apart in a particle accelerator. In this case there is a lot of information flying out, but there's also a lot of energy being put in.

In a sense, the only thing we can ever know about the hydrogen atom are the things we can compute and measure. At some point, we have to write information to a hard drive, whether it is our brain or a SSD, we have to observe it. The hydrogen atom exists as a sketch on a page, equations on a chalkboard, light coming out of a computer screen, spectral absorption lines on a monitor, pressure in a balloon, a glass of water.

What I'm getting at is since the hydrogen atom is "virtual" in the above sense, is there some final book that can be written, 6.56GB or so, thousands of pages, which tells you *precisely* how to simulate it? Is enough information that no one could possibly distinguish the information they are gathering about this hydrogen atom from one in "real life" (that arena where we obtain information from the cameras in our heads and microphones in our ears and chemical sensors in our face)?

Comment: Hydrogen atom can be in infinite number of possible states, so the ultimate theoretical limit to number of GBs that could be stored in it is $\infty$. How much information could be stored in it in practice depends on the environment (temperature, background noise) and our experimental capabilities (how precisely we can measure position or other properties of the atom).

Comment: We’re talking about the minimum amount of information required to describe a hydrogen atom. The string “a proton and an electron” is a starting point in the English language. Compressing that gives an approximation of the Kolmogorov complexity, but is a terrible model, like drawing a circle with a plus and a smaller one with a minus sign. We’re not talking about using the hydrogen atom as an information storage device. We are trying to build an [very classified].

Comment: I don't understand how measuring the mass of a hydrogen atom confers any information. I know the mass of hydrogen, so measuring the mass of a hydrogen atom provides me zero information. Put differently: could you construct a scheme to send an arbitrary message by successive measurements of the masses of hydrogen atoms?

Comment: > *We’re talking about the minimum amount of information required to describe a hydrogen atom.* It depends on the allowed set of states for the atoms and the level of description. In principle, the set of possible states is infinite, so using natural numbers, you need arbitrarily high numbers to describe arbitrary states, thus you need infinite number of bits. If the set of allowed states is restricted, e.g. only Hamiltonian eigenstates $1..100$, then you may do with finite number of bits.

Comment: If you're asking what is the Kolmogorov complexity of complete book on the theory of the hydrogen atom, I don't think there is an answer - there is no such book.

Comment: d_b, How did you learn the mass of the hydrogen atom? You'll find a chain of cause-and-effect, bits from an H atom cascading through measuring apparatuses and hard drives and books and brains finally landing in yours. @JánLalinský Sure, but every year we get closer to that book, from our initial +/- sketch. This keeps coming up, maybe K-complexity is not clear. Consider a harmonic oscillator. Yes, there are an infinite number of states, the Fock space built from ladder operators, but we can write the whole problem, the Lie algebra, the Hamiltonian, everything down on a few pages of paper.

Comment: *"every year we get closer to that book"* I'm not sure there is such a book. How would we know we are getting closer to it? Maybe it's unreachable.

Comment: It appears that we learn more about the hydrogen atom as time goes on. Not sure, but if we can agree on physical systems containing a finite amount of information, and we formalize physics in the framework of software, perhaps we can just look at the class “hydrogen” as a compressed file and note that it’s approaching our theoretical calculation. I mean, wouldn’t you be surprised if three quarks and an electron contain endless complexity? A bit like someone before calculus claiming a pendulum can’t be fully described by symbols.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to be careful about what counts as information. It may take a certain number of bits to store the mass of the hydrogen atom, but are these bits really stored *in* the hydrogen? Here's a rule of thumb that may help: if a system can store a certain amount of information, then two of those systems should be able to store twice as much. If a given hard drive can store 1 TB of information, then two such hard drives can store 2 TB. Let's look at the various measurements of hydrogen atom properties.

> On the other hand, surely the system contains some information. I can make a measurement of the mass, 1.007825 Da, yielding a handful of bits. I can ask "how many quarks does it contain" and the answer is three, uud, yielding some more bits. I can ask what the possible energy levels of the electron are, and write down the orbitals in a page or so. I can ask what the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are, and get a couple more pages. I can ask more sophisticated questions like how the quarks inside the proton behave.

You could do all of these measurements for one hydrogen atom, but what about two? All of the measurements would come out exactly the same because all hydrogen atoms are exactly the same (assuming you used the same isotope). All electrons are indistinguishable, as are all protons. Because these properties do no vary between individual atoms, it is more correct to say that this information is shared among all hydrogen atoms (or maybe the underlying quantum fields, or something more esoteric). The point is that once you've measured one atom, there's no need to measure any other atom, because they are all the same. There's no more information to be found.

There is a way to store information in a single hydrogen atom. One can manipulate the [quantum state of the electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_number). A hydrogen atom with an electron in the $1s$ orbital with spin-up is measurably distinct from another atom with its electron in a $3d_2$ orbital with spin-down. How much information can be stored depends on the isolation of the atom and the sensitivity of the measuring equipment. Distinguishing $1s$ from $2s$ is easy, $57s$ from $58s$ is practically impossible. You could store one bit per hydrogen atom by defining the ground state as 0 and any excited state as 1. Adding spin-up/spin-down and there's two bits.

Comment: Where else would the bits be stored? They’re being read out of a measuring device from the hydrogen atom to a hard drive. Protons aren’t identical - just probe the quarks, and read it out. I think there’s a misunderstanding about a system storing info and containing info. Do two glass bottles store twice the amount of information as one, or none at all? Like, yes, you can write an arbitrary string into by exciting an electron into the Nth s state. What we’re talking about is internal information, the finite amount of symbols to describe all the s states. This atom is in the ground state.